# mirc - Script to add text to a file on computer

Tags: text, mirc

After 15 years, I dusted off a trivia script and restarted my trivia channel. Problem is that all my questions are more than 15 years old. So I want to give players the opportunity to send in their own questions and answers through the irc channel.
Anyone who can help me out with this?
Users should use !addquestion {their question + answer} And that should be written in a text file on my computer, if possible with the inclusion of their nickname before the question

Comment: There's probably some scripts for this out there, but you'd be well-advised to read the mIRCscript docs and roll your own. SO isn't a code-writing service; you should try to do it yourself, then post here for help, showing your work and detailing the failures you're having problems correcting.

Comment: `!addquote` was a common command that does more or less the same, google for that.